# Error: failed to connect to [localohost:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongod server to test my connection with node js.

Here is the code for app.js which i am trying to run -

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localohost:27017/test',function(err,db){

if(err)
    throw err;

db.mycollection().findOne({},function(err,doc){
if(err)
    throw err;
console.dir(doc);
db.close();

});

console.dir('called');
});
```

When i ran it for first time it gave me an error that mongodb module not found - 
after i installed

```
npm install mongodb
```

I started my mongod server in another cmd.
but when i am running node app.js it gives me error -

```
C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\python pakka\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client
.js:409
          throw err
                ^
Error: failed to connect to [localohost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\python pakka\node_modules\mongodb
\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:546:74)
    at emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\python pakka\node_modules\mongodb
\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:150:15)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\python pakka\node_modules\mongo
db\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:533:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:833:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I am a beginner in this. Can anybody help me out.

Comment: Is it really `localohost`...or is it `localhost`?

Comment: sorry its localhost only ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what tymeJV is saying is that you have a misspelling in your mongodb url. It should be `"mongodb://localhost:27017/test"`, not localohost.

Answer (score 0):

Start Mongod service and then open another terminal as mongo(client) 
create database 'test' and then
insert some documents in 'mycollection'